# Php Parse text to array with contain duplicate key

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, text, duplicates

I want to parse text to array:

text delimited with =>

 First is the key and last is the value

 I will parse the text to an array. If a duplicate key is found, the value is an array with these keys. if not, the value is a string.
The expected result is exactly like this:

```php
Array
(
    [phone] => phone1
    [email] => Array
        (
            [0] => email1
            [1] => email2
            [2] => email3
            [3] => email4
        )

    [fax] => fax1
    [other] => Array
        (
            [0] => other1
            [1] => other2
            [2] => other3
        )

)
```

My Script doesn't work

```php
    <pre>
    <?php
    $txt = "
    phone=>phone1
    email=>email1
    email=>email2
    fax=>fax1
    email=>email3
    other=>other
    other=>other1
    email=>email4
    other=>other
    ";


    $lns = explode("\n", $txt);
    print_r($lns);
    $res = array();
    foreach($lns as $v) {
      $trim = trim($v);
      if($trim != '') {
        list($extName, $extVal) = explode("=>", $v);
        if(array_key_exists($extName, $res)) {
          //echo "eee=$extName, $extVal\n";
          $vv[] = $extVal;
          $value = $vv;
        } else {
          //echo "nnn=$extName, $extVal\n";
          $value = $extVal;
        }
        $res[$extName] = $value;
        
      }
    }
    print_r($res);

    ?>
    </pre>
```

I just get unexpected result :

```
Array
(
    [    phone] => phone1
    [    email] => Array
        (
            [0] => email2
            [1] => email3
            [2] => other1
            [3] => email4
        )

    [    fax] => fax1
    [    other] => Array
        (
            [0] => email2
            [1] => email3
            [2] => other1
            [3] => email4
            [4] => other
        )

)
```

Comment: "_My Script not works_" _What_ doesn't work? Blank page? Wrong results? Server crash?

Comment: its mean that doesnt work as expected.

Comment: `$vv` isn't defined.  Perhaps add `$vv = is_array($res[$extName]) ? $res[$extName] : [$res[$extName]];` just before your `$vv[] = $extVal;` line

Comment: @Rob Eyre. Thats no problem with php 8.2.4 we dont need to define with $vv= array()

Comment: You should also be using the trimmed value in your `explode` call - ie `explode("=>", $trim);`

Comment: @Hida `$vv[]` means 'append a value to the $vv array', but you're not defining what that is, or resetting it for each new call.  That's why you're getting values 'leaking' into the next key.

Comment: It's also why you're missing the value for `email1`.  Basically the value starts out as a simple value `email1`, but when it encounters another email, you need to turn the value into an array with the first element included, then append your new email value.  That's what the suggested line of code does.

Comment: @Rob Eyre. yes I should have to resetting $vv[] but dont know where to place it.

Comment: Just before your array append statement `$vv[]` as suggested above

Answer (score 2):

So I have solve this by create array for key and value.
then use array_unique() and array_keys() function.

```
$txt = "
    phone=>phone1
    email=>email1
    email=>email2
    fax=>fax1
    email=>email3
    other=>other
    other=>other1
    email=>email4
    other=>other
    ";

$rowsArr = explode("\n", $txt);
foreach($rowsArr as $row) {
  $trim = trim($row);
  if($trim != '') {
    list($k, $v) = explode("=>", $row);
    $arr_keys[] = trim($k);
    $arr_vals[] = trim($v);
  }
}

$uniqueKeys = array_unique($arr_keys);
foreach($uniqueKeys as $uniqueKey) {
  $arr_keycheck = array_keys($arr_keys, $uniqueKey);
    if(count($arr_keycheck)>1) {
      $value = array();
      foreach($arr_keycheck as $keyval) {
        $value[] = $arr_vals[$keyval];
      }
    } else {
      $value = $arr_vals[$arr_keycheck[0]];
    }
$result[$uniqueKey] = $value;
}
print_r($result);
```

Which result:

```
Array
(
    [phone] => phone1
    [email] => Array
        (
            [0] => email1
            [1] => email2
            [2] => email3
            [3] => email4
        )

    [fax] => fax1
    [other] => Array
        (
            [0] => other
            [1] => other1
            [2] => other
        )

)
```